# How do I create a single tuple with multivalue attribute?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my MySQL database: `supplier` and `supplier_contact`. I can get data from these tables. How can I generate a single tuple for each `supplier_ID` not two or tree tuple for single `supplier_ID`?

What I need is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
supplier_id | f_name | l_name | Mobile_num | Home_num |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

`mobile_num` and `home_num` are stored in `supplier_contact` table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your supplier_contact table has a 'kind' column, you can join it twice, each time specifying the type as part of the join condition:

```
SELECT s.supplier_id, s.f_name, s.l_name,
 cmob.number as Mobile_num,
 chom.number as Home_num
FROM 
 suppliers AS s
 LEFT JOIN supplier_contact AS cmob ON s.supplier_id = cmob.supplier_id AND cmob.type = 'mobile'
 LEFT JOIN supplier_contact AS chom ON s.supplier_id = chom.supplier_id AND chom.type = 'home'
GROUP BY supplier_id
```

Note that MySQL allows this, but in other RDBMSs, you'd need to use an aggregate function in the SELECT list on the number columns, such as `MAX()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Alternatively, you can do a single join and add a condition to the SELECT list:

```
SELECT s.supplier_id, s.f_name, s.l_name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type = 'mobile', c.number, NULL)) AS Mobile_num,
 GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type = 'home', c.number, NULL)) AS Home_num
FROM 
 suppliers AS s
 LEFT JOIN supplier_contact AS c USING(supplier_id)
GROUP BY supplier_id
```

Comment: great! Be sure to "accept" answers on StackOverflow, it helps you, me, and anyone who stumbles upon this post in the future.